# TextView Too Large to Fit into Software Layer

Tags: android, android-layout, memory-management, textview

I have a `TextView` nested inside a `ScrollView`. The content of the `TextView` depends on the user and can be very long. When I set a "large enough" text size (30sp), the view disappears from the screen and I get the following error:

```
AppCompatTextView not displayed because it is too large to fit into a software layer (or drawing cache), needs 9131520 bytes, only 8294400 available
```

During an animation the text becomes visible again. I suspect that this is due to hardware acceleration that kicks in during animations. When I deactivate the acceleration via `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`, the view stays invisible during animations.

Is there a way to force Android to allow hardware acceleration for every frame, not just during animations? Or would this cost too much energy?

Answer (score 0):

Please you try add at Androidmanifest.xml

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity name="first activity name"/>
    <activity name="second activity name"/>
    <activity name="third activity" android:hardwareAccelarated="false"/>
</application>
```

Comment: This works if you don't expect smooth animations. The animations work for `TextView`s with less text. Unfortunately, for the problematic `TextView`, they don't. Also, the drop shadows of all views are gone. I guess I have to limit the font size.